# replacing illegal characters in strings with in a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a file for which i need to replace all the illegal characters in image names with `_`.

The illegal characters are: `` ~?,[]/\=<>:;'\&$#*()|~`!{}%+ ``.

The image types can be jpg, png, or gif.

A example of this the text with illigal characters in the image names might be

```
INSERT INTO wp_2_cptch_images VALUES (1,'hs$x#f.png',2,0),(2,'t_ixy.png',2,1),(3,'#.png',2,2),(4,'!sample.png',2,3)
```

in  the above example i would hope to see

```
INSERT INTO wp_2_cptch_images VALUES (1,'hs_x_f.png',2,0),(2,'t_ixy.png',2,1),(3,'_.png',2,2),(4,'_sample.png',2,3)
```

Illegal characters that are not part of an image name are ok.

I'm really not sure how to approach this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a few lines of the mysql file. We can't help you parse data you don't show. Is this file loaded in the database? Are you looking for a shell-based solution or a mySQL one?

Comment: I have edited my answer; does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to filter SQL queries manually. This is generally a *bad idea*™, and you should use prepared statements if this is the case.

It also could be that you have been given a bunch of SQL commands you wish to sanitise. Don't do this. This is akin to being asked to fix this: [image: unhappy computer]

rather than to design a fault-tolerant power supply. It is technically possible, but is probably not where you should have started. You would be trying to design an automated system to determine the intent of a command, and that would be a result of an AI, not a bash pipeline.

If instead you have a list of all file names, and you wish to sanitise them using bash tools, you can use `tr`:

```
cat original.txt | tr '~?,[]/\=<>:;'"'"'\&$#*()|~`!{}%+' - > modified.txt
```

The `'"'"'` jiggery-pokery is just for ending the single quotes, giving `"'"` for the literal single quote, and then starting the single quotes again.

Comment: This looks like it will replace ALL special characters though. I ONLY want to replace strings that are obviously image strings?

Comment: @SteveMason then please edit your question as I requested yesterday and show us the data. You are asking us to guess what you need, so it's not surprising if we get it wrong.

Comment: Sorry @terdon i missed your request..

Comment: @SteveMason please ***edit*** your question and add the new information. Make sure to use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code and to also include the output you would want to see from that example. Also make sure to show us examples of data you do NOT want changed if such exist.

Comment: @terdon i have updated .. sorry new here so not off to a good start lol

Comment: @Cyclic3 not santizing anything. This is related to migration automation and needing to work and manipulate the SQL directly in the file. bringing in a docker image, and working through mysql using sql is not an option for countless reasons related to WP

Comment: @SteveMason is this a db file, or a file full of sql queries?

Comment: @Cyclic3 it is in reality a DB file and the above example is the result of a grep that returns the lines with image names so i effectively have the example in a ${VARIABLE}. I then want to work with each filename with in that variable